# Why is "int" convertible to "string"?

Tags: go, reflect

This example shows that int type is convertible to string type. But my question is why?

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    it := reflect.TypeOf(42)
    st := reflect.TypeOf("hello")

    fmt.Printf("%q is convertible to %q: %v\n",
        it, st, it.ConvertibleTo(st))
        // OUTPUT: "int" is convertible to "string": true

    fmt.Printf("%q is convertible to %q: %v\n",
        st, it, st.ConvertibleTo(it))
        // OUTPUT: "string" is convertible to "int": false
}
```

Correct me if I'm wrong. But Shouldn't this be `false` as well?

```golang
reflect.TypeOf(int(0)).ConvertibleTo(reflect.TypeOf("string"))
```

Comment: As @Hymns has noted the `int` to `string` conversion is a raw conversion - and probably not the one you expect. If you want a `string` representation of a particular `int` - use `strconv.Itoa(x)` or `fmt.Sprint(x)`

Comment: For the record, there is an [active proposal](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/3939) to disallow this due to potentially odd/confusing behavior of this conversion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is “int” convertible to “string”?

Because the language spec<sup>1</sup> says so:

> Converting a signed or unsigned integer value to a string type yields a string containing the UTF-8 representation of the integer.

1: [Conversions, section "Conversions to and from a string type"](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of `int` to `string` conversion is to create a string with one unicode character: the character that is identified by that int's number.

See this example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(string(int(1234)))
}
```

[On playground](https://play.golang.org/p/u1_4lAxYvB6)

Output:

```
Ӓ
```

This is because Unicode character 1234 (or U+04D2 in the more standard representation) is:

> CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER
> A WITH DIAERESIS

---

You will also notice that on the Go playground, you'll see a red output from go vet, which is a tool to find common problems in Go programs.  The output warns:

> ./prog.go:8:14: conversion from int to string yields a string of one rune, not a string of digits (did you mean fmt.Sprint(x)?)

This is because this kind of conversion is rather strange and not commonly used, so go vet basically sees it as a potential mistake by default.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I experimented with that. I was using it in a function where I only convert if the values are convertible like float to int, int to float, etc. Converting an int to a string was counterintuitive to me, int to rune is okay, though rune is an alias to int32. If I want to string from int or int from string there are functions from `strconv` package. Anyway, it's a language decision I think.

Comment: The conversion functions in `strconv` are not the same as what you get with `string(someint)`.

Answer (score 0):

The `fmt.Println()` & `fmt.Sprintf()` treat arguments differently.

You can feed `fmt.Println()` anything and it'll print it('s `%v`) - like:

```
fmt.Println(string(97)) // a
```

`fmt.Sprintf()` will work, but give you a warning about `conversion from int to string yields a string of one rune, not a string of digits (did you mean fmt.Sprint(x)?)` if you try something like:

```
x := fmt.Sprintf("%s", string(97))
```

Because `string()` treats integers the "Go" way.

So to print a `rune` correctly (like the `chr()` function in most other languages), one should cast the `int` to `rune` first, like so:

```
x := fmt.Sprintf("%s", string(rune(97)))
```